# How to read a node in a serialized XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to read a node in a serialized XML file. Here is the the first part of the XML file (I'm using a screen cap because pasting ended up with weird formatting):

[image]

And this is the code I'm using to read the XML and the error it's throwing:

[image]

I'm trying to read the `<ScenarioDescription>` node.

As per request, here's the entire XML file. Unfortunately it's just a complete mess. Here is a [link to the XML file](http://riverviewai.com/1st%20Bull%20Run.xml).

Comment: You probably have to use the namespace of the node in your query. I'm more familiar with `XDocument` than `XmlDocument` but I assume they would behave the same regarding namespaces.

Comment: It would be great if you could post the xml and code as inline rather than images

Comment: Added link to XML file. Pasting it inline ended up a mess.

Comment: Your question is a bit of a contradiction in terms. Nodes exist only in the tree representation of XML, not it its serialized representation. But then, your code is looking in the tree representation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to access the `ScenarioDescription` node and its `InnerText`

```cs
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(s);

var root = document.DocumentElement;
var node = root["ScenarioDescription"];
var text = node?.InnerText;
```

`SelectSingleNode` accepts the `xpath` expression, you simply can use `XmlElement` [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_Item_System_String_) instead. Otherwise you'll need to create a [XmlNamespaceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager?view=netframework-4.8) instance and add your root namespace to it

> You can supply the `XmlNamespaceManager` object as a parameter to the
>   `SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode` method of the `XmlDocument` class to
>   execute XPath query expressions that reference namespace-qualified
>   element and attribute name

Comment: Thanks! This worked a charm! Just what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should You would need to specify the namespace. In this particular case, the default namespace is used to declare the `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLib` namespace.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("x", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
var root = xml.DocumentElement;
var test = root.SelectSingleNode("//x:ScenarioDescription",ns);
var scenarioText = test.InnerText;
```